# Support for entity framework Linq statement (with a subquery)?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I'm having a horrible time trying to create a Linq statement. Any thoughts on how to create this subquery linq can work?

**TSQL**:

```
select *
from results r
       join ResultRemarks rr on rr.ResultId = r.Id
       join Remarks rm on rm.Id = rr.RemarkId
where r.QueryId in (select id from Queries where CheckId = 62) 
and rm.IsConclusion = 0;
```

**Db tables**

```
Queries   Results         ResultRemark      Remark
Id (Pk)   Id  (Pk)        Id (Pk)           Id (Pk)
CheckId   QueryId         ResultId          IsConclusion  (bool)
          Link  (string)  RemarkId          Content   (string)
```

**Linq attempt**

```
var remarksInfo = (from r in _dbContext.Results
                           join rr in _dbContext.ResultRemarks on r.Id equals rr.ResultId
                           join rm in _dbContext.Remarks on rr.RemarkId equals rm.Id
                           where rm.IsConclusion == false && r.QueryId == 538
                           // ????
                           //where r.QueryId == _dbContext.Queries.Where(x => x.Id == 62).Select(s => s.Id)
                           //
                           select new Results
                           {
                               LinkUrl = r.Link,
                               Content = rm.Content,
                               CheckId = checkId,
                               QueryId = queryId,
                               ResultId = r.Id
                          }).ToList();
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: added an answer

Comment: We need to see the EF class model including navigation properties. You shouldn't use these manual joins. Also, it would help to have a description of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @GabrielLlorico It's really not necessary to post comments like that. OP will be pinged when answers appear. No need to add more noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
//execute this fist
//ids for r.QueryId
var ids =  _dbContext.Queries.Where(x => x.Id == 62).Select(s => s.Id).ToList();
```

then add this

```
where rm.IsConclusion == false && r.QueryId == 538 &&
where ids.Contains(r.QueryId)
```